# Why are the raw pointer values being overwritten/falling out of scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I have a C++11 function making calls against a legacy C function. I thought it would be good to create worker threads(using `std::thread` that will then pass variables to the C function. However, it would seem that if the thread waits too long to execute, that the pointers then no longer point to valid places in memory.

Example(shorted for brevity/readability, and obviously not production code but recreates the issue):

```
//The C function
void c_func(const char* str1, const char* str2, const char* str3){

    printf("My strings str1: %s, str2: %s, str3: %s\n", str1, str2, str3);
}

...

//C++ calling the function from numerous threads
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> bar;
...
for (auto const& foo : bar)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(c_func, foo[0].c_str(), foo[1].c_str(), (foo[0] + foo[1]).c_str()));
    }
```

The printout will printout garbage at different random times. After some experimenting, I noticed that this does not happen when I change the "C function" to use `std::string` instead of `const char*`. However, that change would mean a ton of re-writes on legacy code...which I would rather not do...

Is there a way to allow this type of multithreaded call without the pointers pointing to garbage if the thread is not executed in time? Or am I stuck with rewriting legacy code to move it to C++...

Comment: You're giving out pointers that are only valid for the life time of the `std::string`s they came from, then merrily go on doing whatever you did on that thread, presumably discarding some of those `std::string`s along the way. That's fundamentally broken, no way around it. That's not really any different to storing the `char *`s in an ordinary data structure, dropping the `string`s, then fetching the `char *`s from where you stored them. Get your lifetimes together.

Comment: @delnan Gotcha, thank you for the input...This is what I suspected but did not want to believe it.

Comment: it's broken even without threading, the `(foo[0] + foo[1]).c_str();` will return garbage because the temporary string will be destroyed after the full expression evaluation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the `c_str()` doesn't prevent the string from being cleaned up. After the function returns and bar is cleaned up then the foo strings are also cleaned up which may be before the thread starts.

You should pass the actual `std::string` (possibly to a wrapper that then extract the `char*` before calling `func`) or otherwise ensure the strings don't get cleaned up before you `join()`ed all the threads.

Comment: That wrapper idea just came to my mind as well. Best of both worlds, not having to rewrite old code but still able to guarantee life of the pointer for the duration of the thread.

Answer (score 7):

The core issue with threading here is that the parent thread will do stuff with the memory at the other end of those pointers, making them invalid.

What you need to do is pass `std::string` into each thread. Not a reference, not a pointer, but a *copy*. Now each thread owns its own copy of the string, which will be automatically cleaned up via the magic of the stack and destructors.

Now you can call `c_str()` on each string copy to get a pointer that will be valid for that thread and not cleaned up in a different scope.